# Expand item inside owl carousel

Tags: jquery, html, slider, carousel, owl-carousel

I have implemented owl carousel in my project. 
(A Sample image below)
[image]
My requirement is to expand the item in the carousel on mouse hover. 
Something like this
[image]

If you check out the code, the "owl-wrapper-outer" class has the css defined with "overflow:hidden"

That makes the item hidden inside the "owl-wrapper-outer" div on mouse hover over the item, which make it something like this.
[image]

I need some help or good suggestions in overcoming this problem.

P.S: There can be many items in the carousel something like the one in the following link.
[Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/custom.html), I have just shown 3 for an example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although I appreciate the pictures you've attached, I would rather have seen your code - possibly in a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: you can overwrite that rule, set overflow-y: visible, and check if its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways the get around this issue:

- set the `li` item, or whatever markup you used to have the `height` of the `item` that is `hovered`, or the `max height` that your items will achieve on hover
- `wrap` the `inner-content` of the `li item`, in a div, and work your way from there, with `position absolute` and some css tinkering here and there

Check out this **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ajkjdw3p/)** **OR** then again you could just `overwrite` that rule with the `overflow: hidden`, with `overflow-y:visible` and check to see if thats more to your taste.

Hope this helps

Comment: @Ashwin no problem-o, glad to help out